# Can a bard 10/sorcerer 1 take 6th-level spells for Magical Secrets because of the way multiclassed spellcasters' slots work?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, multi-classing, bard, spell-slots

I have a Lore bard who multi-classed into sorcerer after level 4 and went back to leveling as a bard. When he reaches 10th level bard (11th level spellcaster), he will have 6th level slots. Can he take 6th-level spells for Magical Secrets because of this?

The PHB states "Choose two spells from any class, including this one. A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table, or a cantrip." But the way multi-classing works means that he no longer uses the bard table and uses the spellcaster multiclass table instead, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

PHB p.164:

> **Spells Known and Prepared.** You determine
>   what spells you know and can prepare for each class
>   individually, as if you were a single-classed member of
>   that class.

You are a 10th level bard, 10th level bards can only know 5th level spells.